# Imagecache with amfphp and flash multiple issues

Tags: php, drupal, image, thumbnails

I inherited a project with drupal and flash, and I'm pretty noobish on the topic so please don't bash me.

What I'm stuck at is that I need to create multiple thumbnails for each uploaded image (5 version to be precise with different settings eg. 150w, 250w,..) I created the presets but I can't seem to understand how imagecache works: it looks like the module builds the thumbnails only after I firs see the images, problem is that after I create the node I'm greeted with this view:

[image]

as you may notice some of the fields can have multiple images.
If I'm correct in my assumption that imagecache only builds thumb when you first access the node why I can't see the images but only the icons? Alternatively is it possible to force imagecache to create the different sizes as soon as the images are uploaded?
If not how does imagecache works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagecache only creates the thumbnails when they are requested the first time, but that should not result in this problem. Check if in your content type (under "display fields") the filefield containing the images is set to display an imagecache preset, not something like "Generic Files".

Comment: It's generic files, but I need to have multiple preset per image, is that possibile?

Comment: You have multiple presets per image, you just have to decide which to display in each case. So you can e.g. set a small image for the teaser and a big one for the main node display. You can also use imagecache presets in views.

Comment: I associated a preset to the field, it works perfectly, but it only creates the thumb for the preset I associated, is possible to make imagecache create the thumb for the other presets?

Comment: They will be automatically created when used, you needn't worry about that. You can check that by manually accessing the path of the picture, just replace the preset name in one of your images paths with another preset name.